# How to Show Icon with Menus in android

Tags: android, android-menu

I want to show icon in Option Menus. I tried many methods but I can't find success.In my toolbar some icon already put but i want icon in my Option menu.
I want same as below image:-

[image]

My menu.xml:-

```
    <menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:icon="@drawable/shoppingcart"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/feed_update_count"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

   <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
    android:title="@string/my_cart"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic"
    android:orderInCategory="11111"
    app:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:title="@string/login"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:icon="@drawable/account"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_order"
        android:title="@string/my_order"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:icon="@drawable/track"
        app:showAsAction="withText"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/wishlist"
        android:title="@string/wishlist"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:icon="@drawable/wishlist"
        app:showAsAction="withText"/>

        </menu>
    </item>



</menu>
```

I am new in android developing anyone can help me how to show icon in option menu. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Menu Icon is not showing in andrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801485/menu-icon-is-not-showing-in-andrid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the overflow menu will disable the icon and only show text, you need some workaround.

**1st way**

You can enable it by adding the following codes into your class

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu)
{
    if(featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null){
        if(menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")){
            try{
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                    "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            }
            catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "onMenuOpened", e);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```

**2nd way**

Create your own overflow item and a nested menu to show both the icon and the text.

Example,

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/overflow"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_overflow_white"
    android:orderInCategory="201"
    android:title="@string/overflow"
    app:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/cab_menu_select_all"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_select_all_grey"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:title="@string/cab_menu_select_all"
                app:showAsAction="always|withText"></item>
        </menu>

</item>
```

Comment: @AnandJain I have updated my answer, check out the second way

Comment: This work but in main Item icon also show three white color dot is not showing.

Comment: can you do a screenshot along with your xml

Answer (score 0):

try this code its works for you

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/action_search"/>
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item
android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/action_location_found"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_menu"
android:orderInCategory="11111"
android:showAsAction="always">
<menu>
<!-- Refresh -->
<item
android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:title="@string/action_refresh"/>
<!-- Help -->
<item
android:id="@+id/action_help"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
android:showAsAction="never"
android:title="@string/action_help"/>
<!-- Check updates -->
<item
android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
android:showAsAction="never"
android:title="@string/action_check_updates"/>
</menu>
</item>
</menu>
- See more at: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-working-android-actionbar#sthash.ArNQTEBF.dpuf
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your menu xml as follow

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/menu_item_action_parameters"
   android:title="@string/text_parameters"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_parameter"
   app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/> >
   <menu>
      <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_dropdown1"
        android:title="@string/dropdown_1" />
      <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_dropdown2"
        android:title="@string/dropdown2" />
      <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_dropdown3"
        android:title="@string/dropdown3" />
    </menu>
</item>

<item
  more item
</item>
```

Then

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.action_dropdown1:
    .....
    return true;

    case R.id.action_dropdown2:
    .....
    return true;

     .....

     default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
     }
```

this is completely working code.Mark this answer up if it helps. :) Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

you Need to add tools:context="your class" to menu tag

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context=".activities.BaseActivity">


   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_notification1"
       android:icon="@drawable/one"
       android:title="action_notification"
       app:showAsAction="always"/>
 <item
       android:id="@+id/action_notification2"
       android:icon="@drawable/two"
       android:title="action_notification"
       app:showAsAction="always"/>
 <item
       android:id="@+id/action_notification3"
       android:icon="@drawable/three"
       android:title="action_notification"
       app:showAsAction="always"/>

 </menu>



 @Override 
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 

         return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

         }
```

you shold write tool:context to menu tag then run you will get icons to your text